# Testing a table directive issue

Tags: angularjs, testing

Following is my directive code:

```
    currentApp.directive('testList', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return{
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<table></table>',
        replace: true,
        compile: function (elem) {
            return function ($scope, elem) {
                var arr = ['Jay', 'John', 'David'];
                angular.forEach(arr, function (val) {
                    elem.append('<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>');


                });
                $compile(elem)($scope);
            }

        }

    }

}]);
```

And this is my test code:

```
describe('Tabletest', function () {

    var element, scope, elem;
    var linkingFn;
    beforeEach(module('angularlearnApp'));

    beforeEach(inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope;
        elem = angular.element('<test-list></test-list> ');
        linkingFn = $compile(elem);
        element = linkingFn(scope);
    }));

    it('Testing table', function () {

        console.info(element);
    });
});
```

This is the output of test:

```
Object{0: <table class="ng-scope">JayJohnDavid</table>, 1:  , length: 2}
```

I am just curious to know why tr and td tag are not appearing here, only values are appearing.

Comment: Not really answering your specific question, but you should really make use of the ng-repeat directive. For example... http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/1511/

Comment: Could you perhaps create a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: I tried with ng-repeat approach however in the test it appears like this:<table class="ng-scope"><tbody><!-- ngRepeat: value in arr --></tbody></table>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You needed `.html()` instead of `.append()`, as the `tr`s are the tables content and you're not appending them to the end of the table. ;)

Also you need to build the table row in the loop before passing it into the table, if not the latest item/name in the index'll keep replacing the previous and you'll end up with a table with only one table row with 'David' as its content.

```
currentApp.directive('testList', ['$compile', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<table/>',
        replace: true,
        link: function ($scope, elem) {
            var arr = ['Jay', 'John', 'David'], trHTML ='';
            angular.forEach(arr, function (val) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + val + '</td></tr>';
            });
            angular.element(elem).html(trHTML);
            $compile(elem)($scope);
        }
    }
}]);
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dcodesmith/3yc4a/)**

Comment: @Asutosh, just out of curiosity, what are you testing for in the table? I tried to test if it contains a specific class but I couldn't seem coz it returned an object as you showed in you question.

Comment: I wanted to check the no of rows whether renderd

Comment: And how do you check that, if you don't mind me asking? What's the syntax? @Asutosh

Comment: Following is the test code I have written    
          it('Testing grid', function () {


        var isscope = element.isolateScope();
        isscope.$apply();
        isscope.currentData = [];
        isscope.loadDataForGrid();
        isscope.$apply();
        expect(element.find("tr").length).toEqual(6);
    });